# I am trying to solve Maximum Area Histogram Problem in c++. But now I am facing Segmentation Error and am not able to resolve it

Tags: c++, stack

I have used the concept of Nearest Smaller to left and Nearest Smaller to right in the array using stack to solve this problem. And then further found the width of Histogram and finally Area by finding the product of give arr[] and width[].

On running code at GFG Practice Section am getting Segmentation Error.

> Runtime Error:
>
> Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
>
> Learn More aboutSeg Fault

```
    // { Driver Code Starts
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


 // } Driver Code Ends

class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to find largest rectangular area possible in a given histogram.
    long long getMaxArea(long long arr[], int n)
    {
        // Your code here
        stack <pair<long long, int>> s1;
        stack <pair<long long, int>> s2;
        vector <int> left;
        vector <int> right;
        vector <int> width;
        vector <int> area;
        
        //Nearest Smaller to left, stored in vector left
        for(int i =0 ; i < n; i++){
            if(s1.size() == 0)
            {
                left.push_back(-1);
            }
            else if(s1.size() > 0 && arr[i] > s1.top().first){
                left.push_back(s1.top().second);
            } 
            else{
                while(s1.size() > 0 && arr[i] <= s1.top().first){
                    s1.pop();
                }
                if(s1.size() == 0){
                    left.push_back(-1);
                }
                else{
                    left.push_back(s1.top().second);
                }
            }
            s1.push({arr[i], i});
        }
        
        //Nearest Smaller to right, stored in vector right
        for(int i =n ; i < 0; i--){
            if(s2.size() == 0)
            {
                right.push_back(n+1);
            }
            else if(s2.size() > 0 && arr[i] > s2.top().first){
                right.push_back(s2.top().second);
            } 
            else{
                while(s2.size() > 0 && arr[i] <= s2.top().first){
                    s2.pop();
                }
                if(s2.size() == 0){
                    right.push_back(n+1);
                }
                else{
                    right.push_back(s2.top().second);
                }
            }
            s2.push({arr[i], i});
        }
        
        //Width of histogram
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            width[i] = right[i] - left[i] - 1;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            area[i] = arr[i] * width[i];
        }
        
        long long max = 0;
        max = *max_element(area.begin(), area.end());
        return max;
    }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.

int main()
 {
    long long t;

    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        
        long long arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        Solution ob;
        cout<<ob.getMaxArea(arr, n)<<endl;
    
    }
    

    return 0;
    }
      // } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: What are the constraints on `n`? `long long arr[n];` could be too large to allocate on the stack, not to mention that VLAs are not standard C++. Consider trying a vector instead.

Comment: please provide a [mre] with inputs and expected outputs. Please also explain what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the segmentation fault because the size of right vector is zero.

the logic implementation of for loop is wrong. It should be:

```
//Nearest Smaller to right, stored in vector right
        for(int i =n ; i > 0; i--)
```

Also it would be better if you init vector with size n in the class function.

Complete code:

```c
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


 // } Driver Code Ends

class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to find largest rectangular area possible in a given histogram.
    long long getMaxArea(long long arr[], int n)
    {
        // Your code here
        stack <pair<long long, int>> s1;
        stack <pair<long long, int>> s2;
        vector <int> left;
        vector <int> right;
        vector <int> width(n,0);
        vector <int> area(n,0);
        
        //Nearest Smaller to left, stored in vector left
        for(int i =0 ; i < n; i++){
            if(s1.size() == 0)
            {
                left.push_back(-1);
            }
            else if(s1.size() > 0 && arr[i] > s1.top().first){
                left.push_back(s1.top().second);
            } 
            else{
                while(s1.size() > 0 && arr[i] <= s1.top().first){
                    s1.pop();
                }
                if(s1.size() == 0){
                    left.push_back(-1);
                }
                else{
                    left.push_back(s1.top().second);
                }
            }
            s1.push({arr[i], i});
        }
        
        //Nearest Smaller to right, stored in vector right
        for(int i =n ; i > 0; i--){
            if(s2.size() == 0)
            {
                right.push_back(n+1);
            }
            else if(s2.size() > 0 && arr[i] > s2.top().first){
                right.push_back(s2.top().second);
            } 
            else{
                while(s2.size() > 0 && arr[i] <= s2.top().first){
                    s2.pop();
                }
                if(s2.size() == 0){
                    right.push_back(n+1);
                }
                else{
                    right.push_back(s2.top().second);
                }
            }
            s2.push({arr[i], i});
        }
       
        //Width of histogram
        cout<<left.size()<<" "<<right.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            
            width[i] = right[i] - left[i] - 1;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            
            area[i] = arr[i] * width[i];
        }
        
        long long max = 0;
        max = *max_element(area.begin(), area.end());
        
        return max;
    }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.

int main()
 {
    long long t;

    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        
        long long arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        Solution ob;
        
        cout<<ob.getMaxArea(arr, n)<<endl;
    
    }
    

    return 0;
    }
```